# Быстрая замена содержимого std::string?

Tags: c++

Предположим есть класс, который хранит в себе переменную-член `std::string anyStr;`.
Допустим в одном из методов есть такой код:

```
void foo() {
  // ....
  std::string str{/*указатель на c_str*/, /*размер массива*/};
  anyStr = std::move(str);
  // ....
}
```

И вроде все хорошо, но здесь сначала создается контейнер string, а потом уже перемещается в переменную-член. Можно ли как-то еще больше ускорить этот процесс замены содержимого? У контейнеров вроде вектора, например, есть метод emplace, который позволяет избежать лишнего создания объекта.

Comment: [`assign`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/assign)?

Comment: @wololo невнимательно смотрел доку... Думаю то, что нужно. Вопрос: Будет ли увеличена производительность при использовании assign? Ведь, с одной стороны, у нас assign копирует строку, а при создании нового объекта мы его потом перемещаем.

Comment: Конструктор принимающий указатель/размер также копирует строку. При условии, что перемещение имеет константную сложность, оба способа имеют линейную сложность. Думаю `assign` предоставляет больше возможностей для оптимизации, но нужно проверять. От плохой реализации никто не застрахован.

Comment: Если вы хотите хранить в строке только данные, которые хранятся сегменте констант, тогда вам ненужно копировать данные каждый раз. Достатосно копирования указателя. Посмотрите в сторону string_view, вместо string.